# mysql query SELECT doesn't work with returning single values

Tags: php, mysql, row

I looked for an answer prior to writing this but found nothing, but feel free to post a link if I missed it.

I am trying to get the values from a single row of my mysql table. The query I'm using below returns nothing; the echo of mysql_num_rows is always zero. I know the title variable used in WHERE is valid and the database is connected, etc.. Thanks in advanced.

```
$title = $_REQUEST["title"];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links WHERE title = '$title'");
if(!$query) {
    die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
}
echo mysql_num_rows($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);//also tried mysql_fetch_array
$link = $row['link'];
$type = $row['type'];
$user = $row['user'];
$date = $row['date'];
$rating = $row['rating'];
$info = $row['info'];
```

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection, just FYI.

Comment: Please, for the love of all that is sacred, don't put request parameters directly into database queries. You're just *begging* for a SQL injection attack against your web app if you do that.

Comment: So you know your SQL is returning something? Try testing with just `SELECT * FROM links` first.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["title"]);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links WHERE title LIKE '$title'");
echo $query // run it in mysql prompt to check if there are any results first.
if(!$query) {
    die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
}
echo mysql_num_rows($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);//also tried mysql_fetch_array
$link = $row['link'];
$type = $row['type'];
$user = $row['user'];
$date = $row['date'];
$rating = $row['rating'];
$info = $row['info'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$title = $_REQUEST["title"];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links WHERE title = '$title'");
if(!$query) {
die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
}
echo mysql_num_rows($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($query))
 { 
  $link = $row['link'];
    $type = $row['type'];
    $user = $row['user'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    $rating = $row['rating'];
    $info = $row['info'];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If mysql_num_rows returns zero it means that your query is probably not selecting anything from the database. You have to check if your sql query is actualy selecting anything. Check the value of the $title variable and try excecuting the query directly to your database.

You are also vulnerable to **sql injections**. Always filter user input. You can use mysql_real_escape_string and htmlspecialchars for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting values without a where just like this one:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links") or die(mysql_error());
```

If there is wrong it should prompt you the error.

Many people are already saying it but try to cleanse the request parameters ^_^

Answer (score 0):

One common thing to do is print out your sql query to make sure its what you expect.

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE title='".$title."'";
$query = mysql_query($sqlquery);
echo $sqlquery;
```

also, as has already been mentioned... you're vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

you should use 
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($query){...} and also use mysql_real_escape_string to avoid sql injection. And also dont use echo command infront of mysql_num_rows. And even i think its not necessary to get number of rows to execute the remaining part of the script.

P.s i'm on mobile so i'm not able to post script.